# How to deploy spark with mesos on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, docker, mesos

I installed mesos and docker on AWS, and I tried to deploy spark, but when sends an executor happend this:

> *ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Executor self-exiting due to : Unable to create executor due to Cannot assign requested address:
>   Service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService'
>   failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly
>   setting the appropriate binding address for the service
>   'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' (for
>   example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct
>   binding address.*

I configured all with publics IP's just zookeeper local, but the executor was created in a local IP, so cannot assign request address in a public IP (slave).

If I do all the configuration with locals IP's, the sandbox (in mesos ui) does not work because is looking for a local IP.

I tried

```
set e - SPARK_LOCAL_IP : 'local IP'
set e - SPARK_LOCAL_IP : 'public IP'
set -- conf spark.driver.bindAddress= local IP
set -- conf spark.driver.bindAddress= public IP
```

I tried change the advertise_ip file with 'public IP' and hostname file with 'local IP'

**Is there an specific configuration on AWS or Mesos to make work mesos and apps without network problem (public & local IP's)?**

--Versions--
Mesos 1.5.0
Spark 2.3.0
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Docker 1.13.1-cs9